# Timeout error when connecting to imap.googlemail.com on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

In one of our scenario, I have to programmatically check the Gmail inbox and extract some values from a simple java program.
For that, I'm using `javax.mail` library.

The program working super fine and extract the Gmail inbox data when I execute it in y local environment.
But when I execute the same program in AWS EC2 instance, I'm getting a time-out error.
Saying it can't connect to `imap.googlemail.com`.

Below is the exact error I'm getting in my IDE.

```
Couldn't connect to host, port: imap.googlemail.com, 993; timeout -1
```

Then I try to ping `imap.googlemail.com` from the same EC2 server, and I'm getting a time-out error.

What might be the issue for this and how am I supposed to fix this.

Comment: If your EC2 instance cannot ping, please check ICMP outbound rule of security group. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/security-group-rules-reference.html#sg-rules-ping

Comment: What are the Outbound rules on the Security Group(s) attached to the instance? Does it have general internet connectivity (eg `curl google.com`)?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes, the Ec2 has internet connectivity.